# Need better switching between windows of application

Tags: shortcut-keys, application-switcher

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 (with Gnome and X11 if that matters). My usual workload is to have a few Firefox windows, about 5 Sublime Text windows, and 4-8 terminal windows open. I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tilde</kbd> a lot: <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get to the right application, then <kbd>Tilde</kbd> to page through the windows of that application.

The problem is that with Sublime Text and Terminal in particular, the clues given by the switcher (the window title and the thumbnail) are not informative enough to pick the right window. So I spend a lot of time going

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tilde</kbd> ... no
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tilde</kbd>-<kbd>Tilde</kbd> ... no
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-3x-<kbd>Tilde</kbd>... no
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-4x-<kbd>Tilde</kbd>... no
- and so on.

Is there any way to make this better?
Possible ways I could imagine:

1. Change the switcher logic from a stack to a queue, so the most recent window goes to the back of the line; this would let me inspect all the windows with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tilde</kbd> instead of the ever-increasing number of tildes?
2. Allow manually setting the window title persistently so that I could give the windows meaningful names?
3. Some totally different switching technique like tagging a window with a direct shortcut key or something?

Comment: You may also be able to use the mouse (scroll wheel or pointer) to change windows.  Maybe try super-tilde instead and then use mouse?

Answer (score 0):

To (1), it just occurred to me that using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>tilde</kbd> kind of gets what I want.  A little clunky so I'm definitely interested in other approaches.

Comment: @zx485 I rely on [this guidance](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions) that answering your own questions is OK.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'd just assumed that you wanted a different approach from the ones you already have given in your question. Nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

The title of the terminal doesn't change all by itself.  Something changes it.  Most typically, the shell prompt changes the title.

So if you edit your shell init files and remove the title setting code there, then you can use something like xtitle to set the title from a command to label the window.   There are many alternative ways to set the title.